# HttpContext.Current.Response.Write - Suddenly Stops Working

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am exporting data table to excel using 'HttpContext.Current.Response.Write'. It was working fine till 2 days back. But Suddenly, when i export, i can see only blank excel file.

I have used the following code.

```
            table.RenderControl(htw);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(style);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString().Replace("td", "td class='text'"));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

I am sure that recently  i haven't done any changes there.

Comment: most likely because of this : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3181507

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that too. Still no luck. I have tried open the downloaded excel in Notepad++, its showing some XML related lines...<style> .text { mso-number-format:\@; } </style> <table border="0" style="border-color:Black;border-style:Solid;">.......................

Comment: Also, in my local environment it was working...Whereas in servers, it was not working...